# Xamarin Forms - Android 8 Button Effect

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've got a client which has noticed a little gray box appearing in the corner of buttons on click, on Android 8 when using an app in Xamarin.Forms. Does anyone know if this is just expected behavior or if it's an issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check if the behavior matches [this](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/2096) bug in Xamarin.Forms

If so, and you do need to set a background color, the only workaround I found is to set a color filter instead of the Control's background color

```
Control.Background.SetColorFilter(backgroundColor.ToAndroid(), PorterDuff.Mode.SrcIn);
```